Counting number of references in a sentence
Is there a way to define a command to count the number of indicated references cited via multiple \ref{} commands?
For example:
The following **3** references are listed in my university's good list: \ref{top1}, \ref{top3}, and \ref{top7} while the following **2** references are listed in my university's poor list: \ref{top2}, \ref{top4}. 

The new command should give the answer "3" and "2" for the two lists.

@Mico yes, this is a good objective to formulate my problem.

Should these be \cite, not \ref?

Based on the word "references" and the context of good/bad lists, I'm going to assume that you actually want to count citations to external sources, not references to internal labels.  I've updated the sampel accordingly.  Here's an approach using LaTeX.
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{citeCountInCiteEnvironment}
\newcounter{totalCiteEnvironments}
\AddToHook{cmd/cite/before}{\refstepcounter{citeCountInCiteEnvironment}}
\newenvironment{countCites}{%
 \stepcounter{totalCiteEnvironments}%
 \ref{citesInEnvironment\arabic{totalCiteEnvironments}}%
 \setcounter{citeCountInCiteEnvironment}{0}%
}{%
 \label{citesInEnvironment\arabic{totalCiteEnvironments}}%
}

\begin{document}

The following \begin{countCites} references are listed in my university's good list: \cite{top1}, \cite{top3}, and \cite{top7}\end{countCites}, while the following \begin{countCites} references are listed in my university's poor list: \cite{top2}, \cite{top4}.\end{countCites}

\bigskip

The following \begin{countCites} references are listed in my university's good list: \cite{top1}, \cite{top2}, \cite{top3}, and \cite{top4}\end{countCites}, while the following \begin{countCites} references are listed in my university's poor list: \cite{top5}, \cite{top6}, and \cite{top7}.\end{countCites}

\end{document}


Note that because this uses an environment, it will break if you improperly nest with some other environment.  Also, if you actually did want to count references to internal labels, then you would need to change the hook to cmd/ref/before.  You would probably also want to change the counter, environment, and labels to talk about refs instead of cites, but that would be an internal source code decision depending on how confusing your want your source code to be.

this is wonderful, and simple. I replaced "cmd/cite/before" with "cmd/ref/before" as you suggested. Could we remove the hyperlink on the number created (e.g., on the "3" in "3 references")?

Or, at least change its color or underline or italicize?

@bissi My example doesn't create a hyperlink, so you're doing something to cause that to happen.  Presumably, that something is \usepackage{hyperref}.  In that case, making a ref without a link is simply a matter of adding a * in \ref*{ citesInEnvironment\arabic{totalCiteEnvironments}}%.

I confirm the above comment works perfectly. This completes the answer.
